# Can HDPARM Secure Erase only one partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, secure-erase, hdparm

My question is **not** about how to erase an SSD with HDPARM. I have already done that but I am not sure if the process was completely successful (due to my own fault).

When performing the **enhanced secure erase**, I issued the `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced pw /dev/sda1` command instead of just `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced pw /dev/sda`.

I am completely new to Linux, so I did not realize that `sda1` only meant the partition. I have already sold that SSD and the question just occurred - is it possible that there was some data left on the SSD after the process? When I inspected the drive it seemed empty, **the whole volume was** `Unkown`, and when I plugged it into a Windows machine it seemed empty there as well without any partitions.

Should I worry about my data, or contact the customer? Or HDPARM could have recognized the whole disk by the first partition and performed a complete secure erase?

Except this, I followed the instructions and everything seemed to work fine. After the erase I ran the `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M status=progress` command as well.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you ran `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda...` on the whole disk then what is the problem? What is your question?  Of course there's no file system or data-- this command would have overwritten every single byte of data. If you allowed it to complete, then nothing is recoverable.

Comment: @Nmath from a bit of Googling it seems on SSDs the `dd if=/dev/zero.....` does not "overwrite every single byte of data." In particular, the parts of the SSD used for wear leveling is not overwritten. So in theory some random data (4%?) may still be hiding in there. From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/97ae8k/wiping_ssd_with_dd/):

Comment: From reddit: "With your dd command, you are also somewhat relying on the controller doing its job correctly. The drive that your computer sees is not the actual memory cells. The real drive has a bunch of extra memory that is not visible and won't be wiped."

Comment: @user68186 it would overwrite all user addressable space

Comment: @Nmath fair enough. This is a "belts and suspenders" kind of approach. If at least one of the two commands should do its job.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly, I don't need to worry much about my data. 4% of it may be recoverable if the buyer has malicious intents but otherwise it' cool?

Comment: I am not a hardware expert to give you a definitive answer. The 4% is what I saw while Googling the use of `dd` on SSD. My understanding is that the buyer will need to take the SSD apart pull out the data chips and connect them to special equipment to read the raw information to get to that "4%".

Comment: This sound reassuring, thank you for your help!